# How to add content security policy in Node Js?

Tags: node.js, angular

How to set headers for content security policy...

I tried it in Angular and set the headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set header in `app.js`:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    "frame-ancestors 'self'; default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'; font-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  blob: data: 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'"
  );
  next();
});
```